# Get PackageInfo from RunningAppProcessInfo

Tags: android, android-location, android-package-managers

I am writing a service that uses location information.  I want to know if any of the activities running use GPS.  I want this service to use passive mode if there is an application running which has already started making request for GPS location. Examples of such an application might be Waze or Google maps.  If not such application is running, I want to call requestLocationUpdates using the GPS provider.

As far as I can tell, LocationManager does not have an API that tells you whether there are outstanding requests for GPS location. Is there some way of finding outstanding requests other that those generated by my application?

Comment: I can't rely on PASSIVE_PROVIDER because I don't know if an application using GPS is working. What is the oldest API that supports LocationClient?

Comment: Sorry, I replaced my comment with my answer in parallel with your reply. "What is the oldest API that supports LocationClient?" `LocationClient` is in the Play Services SDK, and AFAIK it works back to Android 2.2.